# How to populate data in same collection with nested _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to populate data in the same collection.
The document is having a key called **uploads** which have array of objects. I need to use same data based on **_id** in the same collection. under **university.mediaOptions.schedule.poe._upload** I have saved the same **_id** which is maped to **university.uploads._id** .

I tried like this :

```
{
     path: 'university.mediaOptions.schedule.poe._upload',
     model: 'campus.uploads._id',
     select: 'name url'
}
```

Sample Document :

```
db.university.findOne();

Output: {
        _id: "122321"
    uploads: [{
        _id: "1",
        name: "Sham",
        url: "www.sample.com"
    }],
    university: {
       mediaOptions: [{
        schedule: [

            {
                _id: "21"
                poe: [{ _upload: "1" }]
            }
        ]
      }]
    }


}


var populate = [
    {
        path: 'university.mediaOptions.schedule.poe._upload',
        model: 'campus.uploads._id',
        select: 'name url'
    },
]
```

Got an error **"Schema hasn't been registered for model "university.uploads._id"**

```
Expected Output: {
        _id: "122321"
    uploads: [{
        _id: "1",
        name: "Sham",
        url: "www.sample.com"
    }],
    university: {
       mediaOptions: [{
        schedule: [

            {
                _id: "21"
                poe: [{ _upload: {
                      _id: "1",
                      name: "Sham",
                      url: "www.sample.com"
                 } }]
            }
        ]
      }]
    }


}
```

Using mongoose

Comment: it seems you have not added the model name in the schema definition for upload.

Comment: I did not get you, The model name is added. I am not sure that can we specify model  property.